# Place label in top left corner of subfigure

Tags: matplotlib

I am making a figure with several panels ("subfigures"). I want to place a label ("(a)", "(b)", ...) in the top left corner of each of the panels.

My question: How do I place a label at relative figure coordinates `(0, 1)` (top-left of the panel) in such a way that:

- the specification is independent of aspect ratio, data, etc.;
- it is the true top-left (it does not add or leaves a margin)?

---

### Current solution

My current solution is this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, constrained_layout=True)

ax = axes[0]

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.text(-0.2, 1, "(a)", ha="left", va="top", transform=ax.transAxes)

ax = axes[1]

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.text(-0.2, 1, "(b)", ha="left", va="top", transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

What I'm looking to improve is that the horizontal `-0.2` needs to be tuned every time something like aspect ratio changes. In addition, the vertical `1` needs to be tuned for example when a title is added.

Comment: You can probably do what you are doing and combine with an offset transform in physical units: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#using-offset-transforms-to-create-a-shadow-effect

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks ! It is indeed a solution, but indeed not the solutions where I would have hoped for ;) In short I would hope that there is way to have matplotlib optimise how it wants to and then simply place something on the top-left of the bounding box it created (letting me worry about overlap etc)

Comment: @JodyKlymak I see how your suggestion helps me to set a label at a fixed offset of the axes. But the offset that I need to put will change if the details of my figure change right?

Comment: -0.02 in axes coords will change as the axes size changes.  However specifying the offset in points will always be the same regardless of the axes size.  Beyond that I’m not sure what you mean by “details of the figure”.